# Heroku Subdomain to External Site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, subdomain, ghost

I am hosting my rails application on heroku.com

## My Goal

I want my site `www.example.com` to have a subdomain `www.blog.example.com` that will load my blog at ghost.io

My ghost.io has a different url `www.example.ghost.io`

I don't want the user redirected to the `www.example.ghost.io`, I want the ghost blog to be loaded under the blog subdomain.

Is it possible to do this? If so, how could I achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be done through the DNS settings of your domain name provider, such as GoDaddy, and not through rails. You would create a subdomain entry `www.blog.example.com` that points to the IP address of `www.example.ghost.io`. Here is a guide for GoDaddy; all DNS providers should have a similar guide: https://www.godaddy.com/help/add-a-subdomain-that-points-to-an-ip-address-4080.

Comment: Wow that was much easier than I thought it would be. Thanks!